# Calling variable inside insert()

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two text files which I'm trying to work with in python 2.7.7, structured as in these examples:

sequence_file.txt:

```
MKRPGGAGGGGGSPSLVTMANSSDDGYGGVGMEAEGDVEEEMMACGGGGE
```

positions.txt

```
10
7
4
```

What I want to do is insert a # symbol into the sequence at every position indicated in positions.txt:

```
MKR#PGG#AGGG#GGSPSLVTMANSSDDGYGGVGMEAEGDVEEEMMACGGGGE
```

At the moment, my code is as follows:

```
# Open sequence file, remove newlines:
with open ("sequence_file.txt", "r") as seqfile:
    seqstring=seqfile.read().replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '')

# Turn sequence into list
seqlist = list(sequence)

# Open positions.txt, and use each line as a parameter for the insert() function.
with open("positions.txt") as positions:
    for line in positions:
        insertpoint = line.rstrip('\n')
        seqlist.insert(insertpoint, '#')

seqlist = list(sequence)
```

The last block of that code is where it falls down. I'm trying to have it read the first line, trim the newline character (\n) and then use that line as a variable (insertpoint) in the insert() command. However, whenever I try this it tells me:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "<pyshell#8>", line 4, in <module>
> seqlist.insert(insertpoint, '#')
> TypeError: an integer is required
> ```

If I test it out and try 'print insertpoint' it produces the number correctly, and so my interpretation of the error is that when I use the insert() command it is reading 'insertpoint' as text rather than the variable that was just set.

Can anyone suggest what might be going wrong with this?

Comment: `.insert()` needs to know WHERE in the list to insert. you're not telling it where - you're passing in a random string, not the integer: `Insert an item at a given position. The first argument is the index of the element before which to insert, so a.insert(0, x) inserts at the front of the list, and a.insert(len(a), x) is equivalent to a.append(x).`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens is that [`str.rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) returns a *string*, but `insert()` expects an integer.

**Solution:** Convert that string into an integer:

```
insertpoint = int(line.rstrip('\n'))
```

**Note:** When you print `insertpoint` it is shown without the `''` but it is a string. You can check this by printing its type:

```
print(type(insertpoint)) # <type 'str'>
```

Comment: Thank you! Converting it to an integer did indeed fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you might need to put int() around insertpoint:

```
seqlist.insert(int(insertpoint), '#')
```